# "now "this keword has been deprecated.what can i do to input time

Tags: solidity, remix

pile memory pile = pile(msg.sender,location,style,availabletime,ISBN,intro,cover,status,price,now,0,0);
in this sentence, what keywords i should take to replace now

Answer (score 1):

`now` was an alias `block.timestamp` keyword.

From contracts with solidity version equal or greater than ^0.7.0 you can replace it with the keyword:

```
block.timestamp
```

More information [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block#block-and-transaction-properties).

Comment: In fact, `now` was deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: if i change like this:                                                                                                             pile memory pile = pile(msg.sender,location,style,availabletime,ISBN,intro,cover,status,price,block.timestamp,0,0);                                                                                                                                   TypeError: Struct containing a(nested) mapping cannot beconstructed.                               what can i do